# How to check if the Django-background process is running in server?

Tags: django, linux, django-rest-framework, django-celery, celery-task

The command to start the background process is,
`nohup python manage.py process_tasks &`

Similarly in Linux which is the command used to check running status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using celery?
and what version of Django are you using?
Try This:
Docs- http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=revoke#inspecting-workers

```
$ celery inspect reserved
$ celery inspect active
$ celery inspect registered
$ celery inspect scheduled
```

Comment: Yes I'm using celery, Django 1.11.26

Comment: Doc: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=revoke#inspecting-workers